# wceload.exe not loading the CAB file from a directory.

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have a Windows Mobile 6.0 application installer that has to execute a CAB file as part of it's process. However I cannot get it to install if the CAB file is in a directory.

This DOES WORK:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("wceload.exe", "/silent \\Installer.CAB");
proc.WaitForExit();
```

This DOES NOT WORK:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("wceload.exe", "/silent \\Program Files\\Installer.CAB");
proc.WaitForExit();
```

It appears that because the CAB file is in a directory it is not found.   I have tried it in \temp\ and it does the same.  The only way I can get it to work is by putting the CAB file in the root which seems silly.

Thanks for any help

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a space in the target path (between 'program' and 'files')and no quotes around it.  Try adding in quotes, something like this:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("wceload.exe", "/silent \"\\Program Files\\Installer.CAB\"");
```

or

```
Process proc = Process.Start("wceload.exe", "/silent '\\Program Files\\Installer.CAB'");
```

Comment: Just realised I hadn't commented back.  Worked great.  thanks.